# A real symmetric cannot be similar to an antisymmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, unitary-matrices

prove:

If A is symmetric (with real entries) it is not similar to an antisymmetric matrix

I tried to show this in this way : 
A is symmetric with real entries so it is a unitary diagonalizable matrix.
so $A=PDP^{-1}$ when $D$ is diagonal and $P^{-1}=P^*$
lets assume negatively and get to a contradiction.
suppose $B^T=-B$ similar to A .
so $A=QBQ^{-1}=A^T=-(Q^{-1})^TBQ^T$

( Q is invertible)
I am stuck here , how can I continue in this way ?

Comment: The zero matrix is a symmetric matrix which is similar to an antisymmetric matrix.

Comment: The assertion is incorrect as it stands.

Comment: You probably mean a *non-zero* real symmetric matrix, don't you?

Comment: Yes. Non zero real symetric

Answer (score 2):

A symmetric matrix has only real eigenvalues. An antisymmetric matrix has only purely imaginary eigenvalues. A similarity transformation doesn't change eigenvalues.

So the only way a symmetric matrix can be similar to an antisymmetric matrix is if all eigenvalues are zero. And a symmetric matrix with all eigenvalues equal to zero must be the zero matrix as it is diagonalizable.